# Understand MySQL status statistics for reading data

Tags: mysql, performance

I've checked the status then i executed some process and then i checked the status again. As you'll see in results data_read, pages_reads as well as some other variables has no change ... however rows_read and buffer_pool_read_requests increase. How is this possible?

```
mysql> show status like '%read%';
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                            | Value     |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Com_ha_read                              | 0         |
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0         |
| Handler_read_first                       | 4         |
| Handler_read_key                         | 4         |
| Handler_read_last                        | 0         |
| Handler_read_next                        | 0         |
| Handler_read_prev                        | 0         |
| Handler_read_rnd                         | 0         |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                    | 733       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd        | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead            | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted    | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests         | 70346368  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                 | 147       |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                | 0         |
| Innodb_data_read                         | 4591616   |
| Innodb_data_reads                        | 314       |
| Innodb_pages_read                        | 146       |
| Innodb_rows_read                         | 203648780 |
| Key_read_requests                        | 2         |
| Key_reads                                | 1         |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0         |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0         |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0         |
| Threads_cached                           | 1         |
| Threads_connected                        | 9         |
| Threads_created                          | 54        |
| Threads_running                          | 1         |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like '%read%';
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                            | Value     |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Com_ha_read                              | 0         |
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0         |
| Handler_read_first                       | 4         |
| Handler_read_key                         | 4         |
| Handler_read_last                        | 0         |
| Handler_read_next                        | 0         |
| Handler_read_prev                        | 0         |
| Handler_read_rnd                         | 0         |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                    | 733       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd        | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead            | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted    | 0         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests         | 70358196  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                 | 147       |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                | 0         |
| Innodb_data_read                         | 4591616   |
| Innodb_data_reads                        | 314       |
| Innodb_pages_read                        | 146       |
| Innodb_rows_read                         | 203652780 |
| Key_read_requests                        | 2         |
| Key_reads                                | 1         |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0         |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0         |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0         |
| Threads_cached                           | 1         |
| Threads_connected                        | 9         |
| Threads_created                          | 54        |
| Threads_running                          | 1         |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using and did you run these statements one after the other?

Comment: MySQL 5.X ... and i let some time between them to allow traffic to make significant changes in order to obtain some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Handler%" changes to give me good clues about how much a SELECT has to do:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'Handler%';
```

InnoDB does a lot of things in the background, so "Innodb%" values can change when you are otherwise doing nothing:

Writes are flushed to disk.

Index operations are dealt with.

The undo log is purged.

Readahead occurs, although it is of questionable utility.